# Insert query in MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql

Hi, I want to insert the values in MySQL database and attach my coding below and I am getting error.

---

```
try{
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,"root","root");
     System.out.println("Remote DB connection established");
     PreparedStatement statement=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TBL_MONTHLY_EXPENSES_DETAILS"+
     (AVG_COST, RWDS_INCENT,OTH_EXPENSES,TRAVELLING_EXPENSES,CLIENT_VISITS,REV_RECD)VALUES
     (AVG_COST, RWDS_INCENT,OTH_EXPENSES,TRAVELLING_EXPENSES,CLIENT_VISITS,REV_RECD);
}catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("Remote DataBase connection establishment error.");
     e.printStackTrace();
     pn.setProjectName("Failed");
     System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
}
```

Comment: Aren't there some quotes missing in the  `con.prepareStatement()` call?

Comment: Going to need to see the actual exception message in order to help

Comment: i got error in query.

Comment: Doesn't look like the actual values to insert are being added anywhere.

Comment: can any one modify the above query

Comment: actually i am getting the values and insert in the database

Answer (score 1):

corrections below - you were missing some quotes, and you had not parameterized correctly.

```
try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,"root","root");
            System.out.println("Remote DB connection established");
            PreparedStatement statement=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TBL_MONTHLY_EXPENSES_DETAILS"+
                    "(AVG_COST, RWDS_INCENT,OTH_EXPENSES,TRAVELLING_EXPENSES,CLIENT_VISITS,REV_RECD)VALUES"+
                    "(?,?,?,?,?,?)");


    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Remote DataBase connection establishment error.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        pn.setProjectName("Failed");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
    }
```

Don't forget to use the statement.setX() functions to set the values for each of the ? in the VALUES statement.

Comment: there is some bracket missing

Answer (score 0):

```
int AVG_COST, RWDS_INCENT, OTH_EXPENSES, TRAVELLING_EXPENSES,CLIENT_VISITS, REV_RECD;

PreparedStatement statement=conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TBL_MONTHLY_EXPENSES_DETAILS" +
            "(AVG_COST, RWDS_INCENT,OTH_EXPENSES,TRAVELLING_EXPENSES,CLIENT_VISITS,REV_RECD)" +
            "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 

statement.setInt(1, AVG_COST);
statement.setInt(2, RWDS_INCENT);
statement.setInt(3, OTH_EXPENSES);
statement.setInt(4, TRAVELLING_EXPENSES);
statement.setInt(5, CLIENT_VISITS);
statement.setInt(6, REV_RECD);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: rather than using the variables in the preparedStatement, parameterize it so that it is resilient to injection.  Using the parameters also allows reuse of the prepared statement.  Not reusing the preparedStatement leads to slow performance on repeated insertions.

Comment: suppose i want to store in database where PJT_CODE  and PJT_MONTH and PJT_YEAR

Comment: but i am not updating i want to insert